# Web based text editor capable of dealing with huge text files (>1GB)

Tags: javascript, html, performance, text

I am looking for examples of web based text editors (eg. running inside a web browser) that are capable of dealing with huge text files, few Gigabytes in magnitude.

Also, to avoid the client becoming a memory hog, I was thinking if there is potentially a viable Server/Client solution, sort of transferring to the client only portions of the data at a time and try to keep most operations on the server side.

Tried a few experiments on Google Drive and similar platforms to see if/how they dealt with such files but could not find anything that had an ok performance and did not crash as my test files got larger and larger.

Comment: Do you know of any text editors that can deal with files that large that are not web based? In any case, recommendation questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ups, I am sorry for that, did not mean too violate Stack Overflow policy.

At this time I am looking specifically to solve this issue with a web based solution, as I have working solutions for dealing with such files locally after downloading them (eg. vi).